# Reading from txt file in C using scanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

i have a txt file and i want to read from it. I know that i will have to read 20 lines(each line contain 3 number variables,for instance 10 5 6 and so on)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int x,y,z;
int counter = 0;

FILE *fid;   
fid = fopen(argv[1],"r");

while(counter<20){
    sscanf(fid,"%d%d%d",&x,&y&z);
    //some operations made on x,y,z
    counter=counter+1;
}

fclose(fid) ;
return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it is not working.
I want to go through file and use `sscanf(fid,"%d%d%d",&x,&y,&z)` 20 times.
Maybe i should scanf?I would be grateful if somebody could tell me how to make this working.

Comment: You might like to RTFM here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html (hint: `sscanf()` is to scan from "strings"!)

Comment: Also test if the result of `fopen()` succeeded, that if if `fid` did not got `NULL` assigned.

Comment: What about trying this: https://www.google.ch/search?q=Reading+from+txt+file+in+C+using+scanf

Comment: use `fscanf`. E.g `fscanf(fid,"%d%d%d",&x,&y,&z);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sscanf` takes first argument  of type `const char *`.You are passing the first argument as `FILE *`.

You can use:

1. `fscanf`

OR

2. `fgets` with `sscanf`

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf` should change to `fscanf`

`fscanf` scan file.

`sscanf` scan string.

1. fscanf function

The `fscanf` function reads data from the current position of the specified stream into the locations given by the entries in the argument list, if any. The argument list, if it exists, follows the format string.

```
int fscanf (FILE *:stream, const char *format, …);
```

2.sscanf function

The `sscanf` function reads data from buffer into the locations given by argument list. Reaching the end of the string pointed to by buffer is equivalent to the fscanf function reaching the end-of-file (EOF). If the strings pointed to by buffer and format overlap, the behavior is not defined.

```
int sscanf(const char *buffer, const char *format, …);
```

[Quote from this website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.9/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.09/gtpc2/cpp_fscanf-scanf-sscanf.html?cp=SSB23S_1.1.0.9%2F0-3-8-1-0-5-7)